# JS: Можно ли использовать пустую строку как ключ словаря или объекта

Tags: javascript, строки, словари

Опытным путём выяснил, что этот код работает в нескольких браузерах:

```
var countsByStatus = { 
  '': 23, // неизвестный статус
  'started': 45,
  'draft': 3,
  'accepted': 23,
  'hold': 2345,
  'fixed': 2,
  'published': 345
}
```

Здесь хранятся число элементов с разными статусами, и некоторые могут быть без статуса. Их количество прибавляются к элементу с ключом *"пустая строка",* что как раз и значит *"нет статуса"*. Такой подход выглядит простым и понятным, но я не уверен, является ли он правильным, везде ли поддерживается?

<sub>Перевод [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8343938/5308802).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8343938/5812238

Comment: @diraria добавлять в комменте ссылку на оригинал, если она уже есть внизу моего вопроса?)

Comment: это специальный комментарий, система обработает его и добавит ссылка на странице enSO вопроса на этот вопрос. [подробнее на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4409/Ассоциация-вопросов-между-сайтами-доступна).

Comment: `Опытным путём выяснил, что этот код работает в нескольких браузерах` вопрос начинается с юмора. Это же синтаксис, батенька, неужто итак не знали что работает?

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр это _перевод_ вопроса, я и так убрал из него многие неточные высказывания.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что ассоциативные массивы (в которых индексом может быть не только число, словари) во многих языках работают с хэшами ключей, а пустая строка тоже имеет хэш: `md5('') == d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`. С поддержкой этого функционала проблем быть не должно, главное, чтобы это решение подходило под смысл вашей задачи.

Для полноты ответа рассмотрим смежные вопросы по использованию пустых строк как ключей:

```
o = {...} // какой-нибудь объект/словарь

o. = 2; // обращение как к полю объекта с пустой строкой не сработает
o.'' = 2; // так тоже
o[''] = 2; // только как к словарю
```

Другие примеры использования:

```
o[null] // вернёт o['null']
o[undefined] // вернёт o['undefined']
```

Дело в том, что `null` и `undefined` это специальные объекты в JS, а не какие-то значения, которые имеют хэш, при переводе к строке они превращаются в свои названия. Преобразовать `null` и `undefined` в пустую строку `''` можно так:

```
key = key || '';
```

А чтобы привести не строковые типы к строке можно просто прибавить пустую строку:

```
key = '' + key;
```

При этом учтите, что `0` превратится в пустую строку `''`, в то время как строка `'0'` остаётся самой собой: `'0'`.

<sub>Перевод [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8347744/5308802) и некоторых комментариев.</sub>

Comment: что за отсебятина про хэши и ассоциативные массивы?

Comment: @Grundy что-то не нравится? И это не отсебятина, а "Перевод этого ответа и некоторых комментариев" – второй комментарий к оригинальному вопросу. На мой взгляд, интересная информация, стоило упомянуть.

Comment: Да, к яваскрипту слабоприменимо. Вопрос все-таки по конкретному языку